# Symfony2 + FOS using simple_form authenticator

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I use [FriendsOfSymfony UserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle). It works when I set everything in firewall as `form_login`, but if I set it to `simple_form` to use [Custom Authenticator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_password_authenticator.html) then it let's me login even if the account is locked or disabled. I want to check if the user comes from the correct IP, that's why I created the custom authenticator, but it seems that some authentication coming from FOS is not processed this way. How can I use `simple_form` with custom authenticator while still keeping full functionality of FOS UserBundle?

Is there some other way I can achieve some other authentication than just the standard? Maybe I'm doing something wrong? I know I can correct this code of my authenticator to check for locked/enabled etc, but I figured - since it's actually already done in FOS - why should I?

**EDIT:** Also, I noticed that when I use `simple_form` the methods of class `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserChecker` aren't being called.

Below is my code of authenticator and `security.yml`:

**config.yml**

```
services:
    login_authenticator:
        class:     Forex\AlchemyBundle\Security\LoginAuthenticator
        arguments: ["@security.encoder_factory"]
```

**security.yml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            simple_form:
                authenticator: login_authenticator
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } # To be removed
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/.*, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

**LoginAuthenticator**

```
<?php

namespace Forex\AlchemyBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;

class LoginAuthenticator implements SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface
{
    private $encoderFactory;

    public function __construct(EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory)
    {
        $this->encoderFactory = $encoderFactory;
    }

    public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
    {
        try {
            $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($token->getUsername());
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException $e) {
            throw new AuthenticationException('Invalid username or password');
        }

        $encoder = $this->encoderFactory->getEncoder($user);
        $passwordValid = $encoder->isPasswordValid(
            $user->getPassword(),
            $token->getCredentials(),
            $user->getSalt()
        );

        if ($passwordValid) {

            $request = Request::createFromGlobals();

            $current_ip = $request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR');

            $user->setLoggedIP($current_ip);

            if (!$user->isValidIP()) {
                throw new AuthenticationException(
                    "You cannot login from your location.",
                    100
                );
            }

            return new UsernamePasswordToken(
                $user,
                $user->getPassword(),
                $providerKey,
                $user->getRoles()
            );
        } else {
            // TODO: Check if there weren't too many tries to login
        }

        throw new AuthenticationException('Invalid username or password');
    }

    public function supportsToken(TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return $token instanceof UsernamePasswordToken
            && $token->getProviderKey() === $providerKey;
    }

    public function createToken(Request $request, $username, $password, $providerKey)
    {
        return new UsernamePasswordToken($username, $password, $providerKey);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you need to create a custom provider for you custom authenticator and add another section to your firewall using your custom provider plus `http_basic: ~` (for basic authentication); and keep the current section in firewall for FOS bundle

Comment: I wanted to avoid creating custom provider - wasn't it an idea behind SimpleForm to not have to create it?

Comment: So you mean merge the custom authenticator and FOS without creating custom provider, right?

Comment: yes. It seems it works, just that standard `UserAuthenticationProvider` calls class `UserChecker` and `SimpleAuthenticationProvider` doesn't. I think I will just import `UserChecker` and call it's methods myself inside LoginAuthenticator. I'm just worried that some other functionality might not work like it should and I might not be aware of that.

Comment: That might work, too. I am not sure if this may help but how about not only implement the `SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface` but also extend the FOSUserBundle authenticator? In this case you need to make sure not to override the parent functions.

Comment: I'm not really sure if FOSUserBundle even has authenticator - remember it doesn't create its own AuthenticationProvider

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. Here is how I solved it.

You must call checkPreAuth() and checkPostAuth() methods of your UserChecker class from within the authenticateToken() method in your Authenticator.

That is done this way:

1) Configure the user_checker service:

```
services:
    app.user_checker:
        class: AppBundle\Security\UserChecker
```

2) Configure the autenticator as a service and inject the user_checker service:

```
services:
    app.my_authenticator:
        class:     AppBundle\Security\MyAuthenticator
        arguments: ["@app.user_checker", "@security.password_encoder"]
```

3) Now you can call checkPreAuth() and checkPostAuth()  on authenticateToken()

Anyway I think symfony approach is the right one, because in my case y needed to perform different checks in simple_form than in login_form.