# Throwing an AuthenticationException but access to secured area still allowed

Tags: symfony

Our legacy application has been updated to be using Symfony 2.7 and simple_form authentication seems to work fine. Now trying to add some more logic into the custom authenticator class and receiving some unexpected behavior.

Here is what happens:

- The user can login with the correct credentials.
- When incorrect credentials are provided, the user is redirected back to the login path, with the appropriate error shown on the form.
- **The problem:** In the custom authenticator class we check a condition and then throw an AuthenticationException. However the login is still successful and the user receives the role of "USER".

The question is: ***Is this the expected behavior?***

The reason I ask is that we have this legacy PHP app that has been converted to Symfony and I was not involved in this initial conversion process. So it is possible that the authentication system may have been altered in order to facilitate this process, but I am unable to track down what is going on.

So far I have used [this page](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/security/custom_password_authenticator.html) as a reference, and tried the suggestions to [create a custom exception listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177984/handle-authentication-exception-with-symfony2), [calling pre-/post-auth methods on the UserChecker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501777/symfony2-fos-using-simple-form-authenticator), and several other alternatives. None have been able to alleviate the behavior of the "ignoring" of the AuthenticationException thrown in the custom authenticator's authenticateToken method.

```
# security.yml
security:
providers:
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: AccountBundle:User
firewalls:
    default:
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic: ~
        provider: our_db_provider
        simple_form:
            authenticator: our_authenticator
            login_path: /secure/login/
            check_path: /secure/login_check/
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        access_control:
            - { path: ^/secure/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
            - { path: ^/account/, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https }
```

---

```
# custom authenticator class
class OurAuthenticator implements SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface
{
    public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
    {
        throw new AuthenticationException('$error');
    }

    public function supportsToken(TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return $token instanceof UsernamePasswordToken && $token->getProviderKey() === $providerKey;
    }

    public function createToken(Request $request, $username, $password, $providerKey)
    {
        return new UsernamePasswordToken($username, $password, $providerKey);
    }
}
```

As a note, sadly we do not have access to the Symfony profiler in this app.